# Getting Compile error in Microsoft JScript (expected)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I tested  a code with my friend and the code worked and now I wanted to test this again and got a Compile error in Microsoft JScript
Everything worked before

```js
var iTest = 0;
if (iTest) {
 let sText = "This is a template string which can contain variables like ${iTest}";
 console.log(sText);
} else if (!iTest) {
 let fnc = (iRadius, iPi = 3.14) => {
  console.log("The area of the circle with the radius ${iRadius}cm is ${Math.round(iPi * iRadius * iRadius)}cm²");
 }
 fnc(3.14);
} else {
 /* This is never going to be called since else if is already handling the only option besides the if */
}

var fnc = (iAlpha, iBravo, cb) => {
 cb(iAlpha + iBravo);
}

fnc(84,255,(iResult) => {
 console.log(iResult);
});
```

Comment: And I'm a newbie in programming/coding and stuff

Comment: And we need to guess the error?

Answer (score 0):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are not available in JScript. The [latest version of JScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript#Versions) is based on ES5, and those two features are only available in ES2015. And `console` is not available in JScript if you are using the [Windows Script Host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(v=vs.84).aspx); instead, use [`WScript.Echo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8f603s7(v=vs.84).aspx).

```
var iTest = 0;

if (iTest) {
    var sText = "This is a template string which can contain variables like " + iTest;
    WScript.Echo(sText);
} else {
    var fnc = function(iRadius, iPi) {
    iPi = 3.14;
        WScript.Echo("The area of the circle with the radius " + iRadius + "cm is " + Math.round(iPi * iRadius * iRadius) + "cm²");
    }
    fnc(3.14);
}

var fnc = function(iAlpha, iBravo, cb) {
    cb(iAlpha + iBravo);
}

fnc(84, 255, function(iResult) {
    WScript.Echo(iResult);
});
```

It would also be nice if you could  provide more information about the particular error you are getting. This should fix it, but it would make it easier for us to help if we know exactly what the problem is.